# Activity restarts even though "configChanges" for activity is defined with "screenSize" in AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, kotlin, android-manifest, orientation, android-orientation

my application's `activity` is defined in `AndroidManifest.xml` as follows.

```
<activity
            android:name=".ui.activities.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="sensor"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
```

The `screenSize` statement is attached, but when the screen rotation is changed on **API 30** devices, the activity restarts and the `onCreate` method is debugged.

I don't want the activity to restart when the screen rotation changes for all devices.

Is there anyone who can help?

Comment: Try adding `screenLayout`. Out of curiosity, what is the reason you're doing this? When people ask how to do this, it makes me think they may not be aware of better solutions to the problem they're trying to avoid. (Most often that ViewModel retains the app state while the resources are reloaded for you.)